Log4j - incorrect date in the backup file
Below is my log4j configuration file, which should be configured as follows:

maximum 5 backups of 20 MB each
backup at midnight regardless of the current size of the main file
deleting logs older than 21 days

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">${sys:user.home}/test</Property>
    </Properties>
 
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/console.log" filePattern="${basePath}/console_backup/console-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%msg</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="00 00 00 * * ?"/>
                <!-- MAKSYMALNY ROZMIAR PLIKU -->
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <!-- MAKSYMALNA ILOSC BACKUPOW -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}/console_backup" >
                    <IfLastModified age="21d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
 
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="name.john.doe.util.gui.ConsoleOutputStream" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

According to the assumption, I would like the log backup to contain the date of the log creation, i.e. the backup was created on July 8, 2024, it should contain the name "console-2024-07-08_1.log" but it contains the date of the previous day ("console -2024-07- 07_1.log”). After changing the logging policy and replacing CronTriggeringPolicy with the <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/> entry, the backup file contains the correct date. Please help me find the cause. I would like to use "CronTriggeringPolicy" because it gives me more options.
The problem is that from time to time the logger stops working, i.e. a backup is created at midnight, the main log file is created but nothing is written to it, restarting the application solves the problem.

This policy is controlled by a timer and is asynchronous to processing log events, so it is possible that log events from the previous or next time period may appear at the beginning or end of the log file. Maybe that's what you're experiencing?

What are you exactly comparing? The name of the archived log files with their creation times? These can differ: on midnight of July 8th app.log is renamed to console-2024-07-07_1.log, because it (mostly) contains logs generated on July 7th.
